# DynamoDB Write capacity used when updating

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am wondering how DynamoDB's write capacity is calculated when updating an existing item that has a ListAttribute.

The generalized concept of the Models are like the following:

```
Model A
id = UUID
name = Str
...other fields

Model A Map Attribute

Model B
id = UUID
modelA_list = ListAttr[Model A Map Attribute]
```

As far as I know, the only relevant calculation information is on new writes, where the capacity is calculated by rounding up to the next KB. So for example, if I have total 899 characters(assume alphanumeric) on all the fields combined, it will be total 999 bytes(including the 100 bytes for one item) which would be 1 WCU. If I have 901 characters, then it will be 2 WCU.

However, if I'm using the UpdateItem on a pre-existing item, then would the calculation be for the additional bytes added to the item, or the entire item? So for example, if I had Model A Map Attribute which takes 1 WCU, and model B has 10 of Model A Map Attribute. If I append another Model A Map Attribute to Model B, would it cost 12 WCU?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how you calculate the WCU  for updating an item:

> DynamoDB considers the size of the item as it appears before and after
>   the update. The provisioned throughput consumed reflects the larger of
>   these item sizes. Even if you update just a subset of the item's
>   attributes, UpdateItem will still consume the full amount of
>   provisioned throughput (the larger of the "before" and "after" item
>   sizes).

Reference: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html#ItemSizeCalculations.Writes

Comment: Does this mean reputting the whole item has the same cost as updating some of its fields?

Comment: If the update has a ConditonExpression that fails (i.e. the doc is not updated), do the write units get consumed anyway?

Comment: @aaa90210 yes, if the conditional expression fails, 2 WCU is consumed for a new item and 1 WCU is consumed for each KB of an existing item.